# Flutter web application is working fine on 'localhost', but when deploying on the server it shows a blank screen

Tags: flutter-web

When I run `flutter run -d`, the Chrome application works fine, but when I deploy on an [hPanel](https://sourceforge.net/software/product/hPanel/) server, it shows a blank screen. This is an inspect console show:

[image]

How can I fix it?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way***, *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69293971/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand the issue.

I am not using the root directory of the website, like "your_domain.com/web", so that is why I have to rename the folder in *index.html* from "/" to "/web/".

Example: In file *index.html*:

<base href="/"> to <base href="/web/">.

Answer (score 1):

THis solution works for me, create a .htaccess file in build/web/ folder & add this configuration, hope it helps

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.html|assets|robots\.txt|favicon\.png)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.html [L]
```